# How to stay on top of OWASP dependencycheck reports

Tags: security, owasp, build-dependencies, snyk

We are using [OWASP dependency check](https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/). It's a great tool, but it reports lots of vulnerabilities. A big proportion of them is false positives. We can suppress them using the [suppression file](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/suppression.html), but with microservices, we have to do it in each repo, which is time-consuming. Is there a better way? We do not have the budget for Snyk and similar tools

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options

1. Share the suppression file, you can specify the remote URL in the dependency check plugins.
2. Use [Dependency Shield](https://www.dependencyshield.com/) to streamline the flow

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `free version of Snyk`. If you disable PR tests you can scan a lot of projects under the 200 scans/month limit
You won't have a centralized reporting but CICD scans should be effective and you can generate local reports and export in JSON